# Exposing the name of the Rules from IBM ODM

Tags: ibm-odm

My requirement is to display all the rules available inside the Decision Server into my GUI. The Business user will decide the set of rules that are necessary to execute in the Decision Server for a particular business case. To achieve this I need to read the rule names from the Decision Server by calling any web-service or reading a database table where the rule names have been stored. So my question is - if there is a WS exposed from Decision Server? Or any table where the rule names are stored by the Decision Server? If not, is there any workaround like running a script which will update the rule names into a table ? I am using IBM ODM 8.5. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make use of ***Queries***.

```
Find all business rules 
such that each business rule is active
```

Queries can also be synced with **Decision Center** or you can create on using **Query** tab in **Decision Center Console**. The result of query would be a list of all active rules and you can further filter the rules if required.

Comment: Hi Akif, Many thanks. Please let me know if I can run the Query from the java code and collect the result there.

Comment: Yes! you can but you need to build eclipse plug-in for the same. Check [this tutorial](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSQP76_8.6.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.samples/designer_smp_topics/smp_rd_brmautoquery.html)

Comment: Hi Ankit, Thanks again, I have checked the code and it is cool. Do you know any REST API that can solve my purpose ODM 8.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Running a query is a good solution for your case. But you wanted the rules to be controlled by the business users. So, write a method which allows us to decide the status of the rule. For Ex:- Deployable, New , Testing etc. Then, you have to write a query to find all the rules which are deployable. Then, you will see all those deployable rules in Decision server not all of them. So, that will help your business users to find required rules and manage them.